# Регулярные выражение: пропустить определенные ссылки

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Добрый день,

есть ссылки которые надо пропускать в **preg_match**

```
/blog
/blog?id=1
/blog?act=new
```

а вот такие нужно не пропускать

```
/blog/
/blog123
/blogingegrge
```

пытался вот так

```
if (preg_match("/^blog+(|[?|A-Za-z0-9=_\-])+$/", $page_url))
```

но не получается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте вот так: `/^\/blog(\?[?|A-Za-z0-9=_-]+)?$/`
Но такое выражение не пропустит:

```
/blog?
```

*Не то, чтобы мне лень — просто, не хочу лишать вас удовольствия закончить задачку самому :)*

Comment: зачем там первый квантификатор-плюс?

Comment: /blog? не не нужны.

Answer (score 0):

Может быть обойтись без регулярки, скажем так:

```
If ((в строке есть символ '?') || (строка == '/blog')) { ... }
```

Comment: am-i-too-intrusive?3;%20DROP%20DATABASE%20xxx;%20--

Comment: Но вообще я писал комментарий (и был слишком ленив, чтобы дописать), что первым делом автору стоит отбросить query string

Comment: что значит отбросить query string?

Comment: знак вопроса и все за ним

Comment: Зачем мне? мне нужны эти параметры.

Comment: @Игорь Чесноков, чтобы не усложнять себе задачу сравнения со строкой, где get-параметров априори нет. Если вы передадите аргумент в функцию и там уже отрежете query string, или скопируете строку, то с исходной ничего не произойдет. Если, конечно, не передавать по ссылке.

Comment: когда всё запросы идут на 1 файл в этом случаи нужно знать какой модуль вывести...

Answer (score 0):

Хотя ответ и принят, но может это выражение больше подходит для ваших целей http://regex101.com/r/eH4oS8 ?

```
((?:^\/blog\?[A-Za-z0-9=_&%-]*$)|(?:^\/blog$))
```

Пропускает

```
/blog
/blog?
/blog?act=new%20act&other-param=other
```

Comment: http://regex101.com/r/uN3wJ8

Comment: @Fike, спасибо! Что-то я перемудрил, прям как индус:))